# interface as method parameter

Tags: java, generics, groovy

I would like to provide an interface in a method call. depending on the given interface the method should create an instance. for this purpose I use generics to provide different kind of interfaces to the method. here an example:

```
static <T> T createClient(T, String endpointAddress) {
  JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean()
  factory.setServiceClass(T.class)
  factory.setAddress(endpointAddress)
  (T) factory.create() // error -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Class is not an interface
}

// AccessibleClient is an interface. call method
createClient(AccessibleClient, "http://localhost/service")
```

I do not know whether my approach is the appropriate solution.

Comment: shouldn't it be `createClient(T param, String endpointAddress)` ?

Comment: How are you expecting to create an instance from an interface ?

Comment: It should be `createClient(AccessibleClient.class, "http://localhost/service")`

Comment: thanks, i changed my code as follows: T params in the method signature factory.setServiceClass(param) and called the method with createClient(AccessibleClient.class, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say `T.class` -- in Java that information is not available at runtime.

As per [gontard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594933/gontard)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012594/inteface-as-method-parameter#comment22837494_16012594), you probably want something like this:

```
static <T> T createClient ( Class<T> t, String endpointAddress )
{
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass( t );
    factory.setAddress( endpointAddress );
    return (T) factory.create();
}

createClient( AccessibleClient.class, "...");
```

(Also, in Java you need semicolons and `return` keywords -- is this Groovy or something?)

Comment: i forgot to mention that i used groovy and not plain java. in groovy this information is avialable at runtime very well and you don't need to use semicolons and returns. i accept your answer because in the context of java it is correct.